# Python: Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x0000015937CEA128>>

Tags: python, excel, selenium, web, web-scraping

Code Used:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import requests, bs4

res = requests.get('http://www.iceomatic.com/Products/Ice-Machines/Cubers/')
icesoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
selectElems = icesoup.select('li')
len(selectElems)
type(selectElems[0])
selectElems[0].getText()
```

The main objective is to get the data of different products into an excel sheet. I just started working on it. Trying to create html objects for further processing.

The following is the output:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of 
<selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x0000026E252CA128>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Santosh\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 163, in __del__
File "C:\Users\Santosh\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 139, in stop
File "C:\Users\Santosh\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 110, in 
send_remote_shutdown_command
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down
```

Please suggest a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you importing all those libs ? You only use `requests` and `bs4`

Comment: Does that cause an issue?. I used those libs for other example. i just retained them.

Comment: No, but it helps debugging  if you keep your code clean. For example, you import `bs4` and `BeautifulSoup` , that's unnecessary. Anyway, your traceback shows there is an issue with selenium, if that helps.

Comment: @t.m.adam Posted a new question.